# Is there any existing web control that permits the entry of both text and images in the manner of

Tags: asp.net

I want to know is if there is any textbox-type web control out there that can approximate Word for simply WYSIWYG editing? 
I am NOT talking about so-called HTML or Rich Text controls.  (In fact I'd prefer if the users didn't play with colors and font sizes.) 
What I need is a control that allows a non-technical user to intutively copy images and paste them in without having to fiddle with HTML tags.
Is this even possible in current web technology?

Answer (score 1):

take a look at the [HtmlEditorExtender](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/HtmlEditorExtender/HTMLEditorExtender.aspx), from asp.net ajax controls can be very simple, and easy to add to your asp.net project.

The full project: http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/demo). You can then customize it so that the options you don't want to show up (color, font size, html editing) don't show up. Otherwise there is no built-in .net control to accomplish this.